# Фильтр по трем значениям

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Здравствуйте. Сделал фильтр по трем значениям. Фильтр по группе и количеству работает, а по наименованию выдает ошибку `Table1:Field 'Имя' not found`.

В чем может быть проблема? Значения количество и группа - числовые, а наименование - строковый тип.

```
procedure TForm2.Button2Click(Sender:
    TObject);   
    begin
        Table1.Filtered:=true;   
        //фильтровать по группе   
        if RadioButton1.Checked then
            Table1.Filter:='Gruppa='+Edit6.Text;    
        //фильтровать по количеству
        if RadioButton2.Checked then
            Table1.Filter:='kolvo='+Edit6.Text;   
        //фильтровать по наименованию   
        if RadioButton3.Checked then
            Table1.Filter:='Naimenov_ed='+Edit6.Text;  
    end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    Table1.Filtered:=true;
```

Как минимум эту строчку в самый низ перенести.

**UPD** 
Экранировать значение по имени ковычками Имя в 'Имя'

Comment: + QuotedStr(Edit6.Text);